# Want to add and subtract items from $scope array

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope

I am using $scope.exchange to send data to an ng3 chart.  I want the chart to add a new value and delete the oldest value.  So I never have more than 3 points.  It currently adds 3 points every second but never removes any.  If I change the line with slice to $scope.exchange = [], the chart will draw the first 3 and never update again.  If I use the while loop that is commented out, then the chart re-draws everything every second.  This flashes the screen and looks ugly.  What can I do?

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('exchange-directives', []);

app.directive('tableRows', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: "js/directives/tableRow.html",
        scope:'=',
        link: function(scope, elements, attrs){
        },
        controller: ['$http', '$timeout', '$scope', function($http, $timeout, $scope) {
          var table = this;
            table.rows = [];
            var count = 0;
            var retrieveItems = function() {
                if($scope.exchange.length != 0) $scope.exchange.slice(3);
                //while($scope.exchange.length){
                //  $scope.exchange.pop();
                //}
                $http.get('/dashboard/history').success(function(data){//change back to '/dashboard/rates' when aws goes back online
                    table.rows = data;
                    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                        var vals  = {
                            x: count++, 
                            dates: data.dates[i],
                            rates: data.rates[i]
                  }
                        $scope.exchange.push(vals);
                    }
                    $timeout(retrieveItems, 1000);
            });
            }
            retrieveItems();

        }],
        controllerAs: "table", 
    };
});
})();
```

Comment: Array slice returns a shallow copy of part of the array. You don't actually modify the array itself.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get around that but the following trial failed.
    $scope.exchange = $scope.exchange.slice(3);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Shashank was on the right track everything was creating a new object that the rest of my code could not accept.  pop() just mutates the current array and therefore is accepted by all parts of the code.  So I had to do

```
this.setHistory = function(input) {
    while($scope.exchange.length){
    $scope.exchange.pop();
    }
    $scope.history = input;
    startup(input, $scope.historyData);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It'd be easier with a fiddle, but here's what I think you want.  First off, I'd "unshift" this new info instead of "pushing" it.  It looks to me like you're currently adding the data to the end, then deleting that same data.  Then I'd pop() the end item, instead of assuming that the object has 3 items.  Next, I'd pass in the number of items you want to load.  I'm not sure how the table.rows array is being used, but I'd guess you want to unshift that as well.

```
var retrieveItems = function(num) {
    num = num || 1;
    if($scope.exchange.length != 0) $scope.exchange.pop();

    $http.get('/dashboard/history').success(function(data){
        table.rows.unshift(data);
        for (i = 0; i < num; i++){
            var vals  = {
                x: count++, 
                dates: data.dates[i],
                rates: data.rates[i]
            }
            $scope.exchange.unshift(vals);
        }
        $timeout(retrieveItems, 1000);
    });
}
retrieveItems(3);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it didn't work.  it is just adding new points to the chart but I don't want the chart to change size.  You right about adding an argument and that was going to be built out once I solve this current issue.  The unshift will not work because I need the oldest data to be for and the newest data last

Comment: I'd need to see how your script is using the data.  Right off the bat, I don't know what "table.rows" is versus "exchange" - they're both using "data".  I'd believe table.rows is not being built properly, but since I can't see how it's being used, I can't say.  Anyway, afraid that's as far as I can go without more info.  Cheers.

Comment: I don't think the table.rows is all that important for this questions but I understand your difficulty.
All the code is here: https://github.com/chad187/StockMarket
and that code does this: http://ec2-52-88-60-196.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/